# Why is the ethereum beacon chain attestations gossip timechart shaped like this?

Tags: ethereum

I'm looking at the live chart of the attestation gossips as they are received from the mesh, and it looks curious. I can see there's a spike at 2/3 of the slot, which corresponds to the aggregated attestations, but it also looks like unaggregated attestations generally arrive in 2 spikes. How could this be explained?

This is from a livestream, that visualizes gossip data from the lighthouse node: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwzKn5sh4nE

[image]